# using ROUND() in php sql

Tags: php, sql

Tried juggling the order around but it doesn't seem to work. Attempting to trunc the result to a full number rather than a decimal.

Current query in php that works to give me a percentage

```
$query_total = "SELECT (COUNT(".$id.")* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$att_tb.")) AS attOverall FROM ".$att_tb;
```

My attempt at using ROUND() to trunc the result (not working)

```
$query_total = "SELECT CAST(ROUND(COUNT(".$id.")* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "$att_tb."),0) AS attOverall) FROM ".$att_tb;
```

A working correction would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what are you counting and getting the percentile?

Comment: Counting $id, which is a column of boolean. The first query gives me 100.00000, which is correct, just too lengthy. I want to drop the decimal places.

Comment: try and replace round with `FLOOR()` ? http://www.w3resource.com/sql/arithmetic-functions/floor-wth-positive-value.php

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. 
Anyone wondering, swapped ROUND for FLOOR and dropped the CAST.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN $id IS NOT NULL THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) AS attOverall
FROM ".$att_tb;
```

You can then cast the value to whatever type you like or use `FORMAT()` to format it as a string.